# Solidity Message Error

Tags: solidity, contract-development

What do these two error messages mean ?

```
Warning Message:

Warning: Unused function parameter. Remove or comment out the variable name to silence this warning.
--> contracts/GabeCoin.sol:120:19:
|
120 | function mint(address account, uint256 id, uint256 amount)
| ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

Warning: Function state mutability can be restricted to pure
--> contracts/GabeCoin.sol:96:9:
|
96 | function uri(uint256 _tokenId) override public view returns (string memory){
| ^ (Relevant source part starts here and spans across multiple lines).
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both of the messages are warnings, not error messages.

The first warning specifies that you have an unused parameter in the function that is not used in the logic of the function definition. The compiler is trying to help you save gas and remove the unused parameter. If you don't want to remove it, you can ignore the warning.

The second warning specifies that the designated function doesn't read the state variable of the contract, also not make any modifications to the contract state variables. `Pure` functions are usually used with an arithmetic calculation without reading any contract state variables or use globally available properties (`msg.data` and `msg.sender`) or functions that do not make state changes (`keccak256()` and `ripemd160()`).

Comment: Thank you this is very helpful in me upstanding.

Comment: P, thxs!

The unused parameters I would like to remove, what do you recommend I remove here.

    function mint (address account, uint256 id, uint256 amount)
    public
    payable {
        require(msg.value== publicPrice);
        _mint(msg.sender, id, amount, "");
    }

Comment: This depends on your design. If you are minting NFT tokens, you can take a look at the ERC721 standard here: https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/2.x/api/token/erc721#ERC721-_mint-address-uint256-